# jquery not inserting html or text inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code inside a webpage:

```
<div id="search_suggest"></div>
```

Trying to use the following inside a javascript code changes the content inside the div brackets.

```
var ss = document.getElementById('search_suggest');
ss.innerHTML = 'asdasdasasddasasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasasdasd';
```

The following  code, using Jquery as a selector, doesnt work (I checked, I'm selecting the right element):

```
  var ss =$(".search_suggest")
  ss.append( "<p>Test</p>"); #doesnt work
  ss.html("<p>Test</p>"); #doesnt work
  ss.text("<p>Test</p>"); #doesnt work
```

I also tried with plain text instead of html. Anyone have any ideas as why one works and the other doesn't? I don't believe I'm doing the tesxt or html wrong.

Comment: Use `id` selector `#` change `$("#search_suggest")` instead of `$(".search_suggest")`

Comment: Its because you are selecting by a class name while u have assigned an ID with that name to your element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`search_suggest` is ID of element. Use id selector `#` instead of class selector `.`:

```
$("#search_suggest")
```

Comment: it worked! I've seen to have been using the # for class and . for id. Strangely enough, nothing has broke so far. Thanks

Comment: @virgula24: you were doing opposite of what needs to be done. use `#` for ID and `.` for class

Answer (score 2):

In Jquery selectors # is used to getElementById is while . is used to getElementsByClassName.

use this `var ss =$("#search_suggest")`
instead of `var ss =$(".search_suggest")`

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion

If you must use a class or attribute selector, you can improve performance by specifying the optional context parameter.

```
ID is absolutely the **fastest**. Part of the reason is that ID is supposed to be unique, so the API stops searching after the ID is found in the DOM.
```

Better to use ::

```
$(".classname", "#idname")
```